# How to resize KDE partition in dual boot windows setup

Tags: partitioning, kde, windows-11

I have a new windows 11 laptop that I installed KDE on in a dual boot setup.  Unfortunately I got the partition size backwards giving KDE the amount that I wanted to leave for Windows.  I have tried to resize the KDE partition in windows disk management and KDE Partition Manager but neither give me the option to do so.  How can I decrease the KDE partition size and increase the windows size?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using LVM, it should be really easy: [here](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/)

If you don't use LVM, it should be a little bit hard because you have to modify the partition table by yourself:
[here!](https://vinfrastructure.it/2018/01/resize-linux-filesystem-without-lvm/)

Comment: Me again - Was just checking your profile and noticed you'd answered a few questions.  Another "newbie tip" -- One of the rules across most of the Stack Exchange sites (like Stack Overflow and Super User) is that, while it is okay to link to a site with the answer, you do need to post enough of the answer here to be useful (see my answer to your question as an example).  This helps make sure that the answer is still useful even when and if the link changes (goes away, etc.).  Thanks, and again, Welcome to the site!

Comment: thank you so much dude!